# Import error for Facebook library 'faiss'. It's throwing DLL load failed error

Tags: python, dll, pytorch, transformer-model, faiss

Import error for Facebook library 'faiss'. It's throwing DLL load failed error

```
import faiss
```

Error is :

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

Can anyone help me with this? I've installed with pip install faiss-cpu and python version is 3.7.9

It's running good in colab, but not in local pc

Comment: Pretty sure it only has Linux support atm; thats why it works on colab

Comment: Ya, but what's the problem with windows? I think most of the Facebook AI libraries throws error while installing libraries

Comment: Please add the entire exception traceback.